# azure node.js express sessions stored on Azure caching

Tags: node.js, session, caching, azure, express

I am trying to store node.js express sessions on Azure caching.

We already set up a dedicated caching on a worker role following this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2013/01/03/november-updates-to-windows-azure-powershell-cmdlets.aspx

```
Add-AzureCacheWorkerRole mycacherole

Enable-AzureMemcacheRole mywebrole mycacherole
```

In the sample, they use mc module

Can you help me on how to stored express session on azure cache using that module?

I also tried connect-memcached https://github.com/balor/connect-memcached as AzureCache:

```
MemcachedStore = require('connect-memcached')(express);

app.use(express.session({ 
     secret: 'CatOnTheKeyboard', 
     store: new MemcachedStore 
 }));
```

We got error with this trace. Is it possible to get express to store it sessions on azureCache? Thank for your help.

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'reverse' of null
    at Client.connect
(E:\approot\node_modules\connect-memcached\node_modules\memcached\lib\memcached.js:129:42)
    at Client.memcachedCommand [as command]
(E:\approot\node_modules\connect-memcached\node_modules\memcached\lib\memcached.js:299:10)
    at Client.get
(E:\approot\node_modules\connect-memcached\node_modules\memcached\lib\memcached.js:794:10)
    at MemcachedStore.get
(E:\approot\node_modules\connect-memcached\lib\connect-memcached.js:82:19)
    at Object.session [as handle]
(E:\approot\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\session.js:309:11)
    at next (E:\approot\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.cookieParser [as handle]
(E:\approot\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\cookieParser.js:60:5)
    at next (E:\approot\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.handle
(E:\approot\node_modules\express-validator\lib\express_validator.js:148:10)
    at next (E:\approot\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
```

Comment: This sounds and looks like an issue with the Node.js module itself; this isn't the result of a call into the cache role afaik from this trace. Can you double-check for known issues or bugs in the memcached lib for connect-memcached?